# How to capture the Icheck checked event in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, icheck

How to capture the iCheck change  event in backbone view.
I am unable to find any reference and using normal change event is not working.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for events backbone.js is

```js
events: {
  'ifChanged #myIdCheckbox': 'changed'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should try to search on the Internet almost all plugins have a web page, this one for example: http://icheck.fronteed.com/

But anyway, to listen to click event Ichecks, you must use `ifChanged` or `check`

```
$('input').on('ifChanged', function (e) {
                var value = $(this).val(); 
                ....
        });
```

You can also use an ID to select a checkbox just by typing: `$('#Id').....`